# Rails: Difficulty in integrating new method to reduce the quantity of an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make a very basic inventory control system using Ruby on Rails, but I have difficulty adding new functionality to supplement the 'show', 'edit' & 'destroy', where by an item (row) in the database has its quantity reduced by 1 when removeItem is selected.

Here is the code I have added to my routes.rb:

```
match 'removeItem' => 'items#removeItem'
```

...my index.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to 'Remove Item', 'removeItem/:#{item}', method: :GET, data { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

...items_controller.rb

```
def removeItem
@item = Item.find(params[:id])

respond to do |format|
 if @item.quantity >=1
   @item.quantity -= 1
     format.html { redirect to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
 else
     format.html { render action: "removeItem"}
     format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
 end
 end
```

The error message I am receiving is 'No routes match [GET] "/removeitem/:". However, I am not sure how to resolve the issue or why the id number is not appearing after the semi-colon.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you get an error message, or bad results, or .... ? Also, is `repsond` really what you should have there, or should it be `respond`?

Comment: Sorry..yes that should be 'respond', that was an error as I had to type out the code again, as the copy & paste doesn't always work for me from VirtualBox (despite have bidirectional clipboard enabled). Also, the error message I am getting is 'No routes match [GET] "/removeitem/:". I am not sure the :#{item} is not converting to the item ID number. Thanks for your help and apologies for not clarifying this in the original post.

Comment: @NamingError I've updated my answer for the problem with the route. You should read this for better understanding: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html

Comment: @Balrick Thanks for the resource. I am still getting errors with regards to the routes, but will check this guide out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the route, the id of the item is missing, and it would make sense to use the http verb DELETE

```
delete 'removeItem/:id' => 'items#removeItem'
```

Update your link to use DELETE verb

```
<%= link_to 'Remove Item', 'removeItem/:{item}', :method => :delete, data { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

---

In the controller:

```
@item.quantity -= 1
```

This line updates the object, but not the database. You should use [`decrement!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/decrement!)

```
respond to do |format|
  if @item.quantity >= 1 && @item.decrement!(:quantity)
    format.html { redirect to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "removeItem"}
    format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: Why use increment -1? Use `decrement!(:quantity)` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/decrement!

Comment: @DamienRoche Thanks, I did not know the method exists

Comment: Glad to make the introduction :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice Baldrick. I am still get an error message though which says: 'No routes match [GET] "/removeitem/:". I am not sure the :#{item} is not converting to the item ID number. Thanks for your help and apologies for not clarifying this in the original post.

Comment: could use `@item.quantity -= 1`, but you would have to do an explicit `update_attribute`. `decrement!` does both for you.